# How to print total count of multiples strings from a text file using awk

Tags: linux, awk

I'm extremely new to awk so I'm having a little bit of trouble with this problem. What I need to do is write a script that prints the counts of three strings "They", "He" "She", but I can only do this in awk and the words are case sensitive. So far it's only printing the number of times "They" appears in the text file (which is an essay), and not the others. Some input on how to do this  only in awk would be great. Here's what I have so far

`awk 'BEGIN {print "They" "  " "He" "  " "She"} #printing header
    {for (i=0;i<=NF;i++)if ( $i =="They" ) numA++;
    if ( $i =="He" ) numB++;
    if ( $i =="She" ) numC++ } END {print numA,"  ", numB, "  ", numC}' myFile.txt`

The expected output should be:

`They  He  She
 24    16   17`

Comment: Provide sample input and expected output. Discuss how to treat substrings (e.g. should "Help" match when looking for "He"?). In your input, cover the cases you think will be difficult to NOT produce false matches because that's always much harder to deal with than the sunny day cases you do want to match.

Comment: @ EdMorton My apologies, I'll go back and edit that information in. Sorry for the lack of sufficient information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the braces for the 'for' loop - you should have :

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "They" "  " "He" "  " "She"} #printing header
    {for (i=0;i<=NF;i++)
        {
            if ( $i =="They" ) numA++;
            if ( $i =="He" ) numB++;
            if ( $i =="She" ) numC++;
         }
} END {print numA,"  ", numB, "  ", numC}' myFile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks so much for noticing that. It worked exactly as it is supposed to with your corrections. Not sure how I overlooked that, but I'm glad another pair of eyes caught it. Thanks again.

Comment: think about how many times the hard-coded word "They" appears in that script and the coupling between the order of fields in the BEGIN and END sections. Now imagine you want to change the order or add or remove a word and compare that effort to what you'd need to do with the solution I posted where all you'd do is modify the words in the string being split() in the BEGIN section and the rest of the script would work as-is.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your input is space-separated lines of individual words, here's how to do it:

```
awk '
BEGIN{
    numWords = split("They He She",tmp)
    for (i in tmp) {
        words[i]
    }
}
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ($i in words) {
            cnt[$i]++
        }
    }
}
END {
    for (wordNr=1; wordNr <= numWords; wordNr++) {
        printf "%s%s", tmp[wordNr], (wordNr<numWords?OFS:ORS)
    }
    for (wordNr=1; wordNr <= numWords; wordNr++) {
        printf "%d%s", cnt[tmp[wordNr]], (wordNr<numWords?OFS:ORS)
    }
}' file
```

If that's not what your input is then update your question to show it.